# Title before author name?

Tags: biblatex

I want to have title before author name in my list of references. How I could achieve that. I am uising the following setup for biblatex:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ydnt, 
bibstyle=authoryear-comp,labelyear=false,defernumbers=true,maxnames=20,firstinits=true, 
uniquename=init,dashed=false]{biblatex}
```

thanks in advance,
sushil

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the driver for the different types by yourself, get the originals from `standard.bbx` and swap the bibmacros by copy/pasting. To keep track, you should place all this in a new `bbx` file and give it a unique name. Having done this, your preamble will be less cluttered.

What i just don't understand, why do you have `authoryear-comp` chosen just for the bibstyle? The important stuff behind `authoryear-comp` happens for the intext citations.

[image: sushilBiblatexSwapAuthorTitle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ydnt, 
    bibstyle=authoryear-comp,labelyear=false,defernumbers=true,maxnames=20,firstinits=true, 
uniquename=init,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%swap
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%swap
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\cite{westfahl:space}

\cite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```